# Is there a way to make user story a subtask of an task?

Tags: jira, jira-agile

I would like to make following hierarchy:

```
Task
   -subtask
      -user story 
      -user story 
   -subtask
      -user story 
      -user story
```

But when I am trying to add user story as a subtask to existing task it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible the way you want.

I suggest the most common approach and that's to use **Epic** -> **Task/Story** -> **Sub-Task** hierarchy.

```
Epic
  - Task or Story
      - Sub-Task
```

The **Sub-Task** is the smallest task in Jira and it doesn't make sense to have any further sub-issues. Moreover, (User) **Story** is bigger piece of delivery than a **Sub-Task**. Common **Tasks** and **Stories** are usually equivalent issues (at the same level) and just used for different type of task.

See also these links at Atlassian Agile Coach:

- https://www.atlassian.com/agile/project-management/epics-stories-themes
- https://www.atlassian.com/agile/project-management/epics
- https://www.atlassian.com/agile/project-management/user-stories

Answer (score 0):

Jira only supports a three level hierarchy with Epic at the top and sub-task at the bottom.

You can use links though. For example you could have a sub-task linked to a number of stories. The linked stories would be visible in the sub-task.